# Does a portal to Alfheim draw mana equally from the two pools?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a portal to Alfheim set up (not yet turned on) with a mana pool to each side as instructed in the Lexica Botania.

One side is powered by some Hydroangeas (slow flowers) and the other side by thermalilies (substantially faster flowers).  I think I have enough mana to open and sustain the portal now between the two sides, but I'm hesitant: will it draw from either side as they have mana or will it draw equally from both?

Will it shut down if one mana pool runs out even if the other has plenty of mana left?

Comment: I think it will draw evenly from both, but you could always experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure I once had a Portal to Alfheim running with only 1 mana pool, but it closed not very long after that because the other mana pool was drained off.

Your best solution here is to try that exact same build in creative, and you can even use the creative mana tablet to fill your mana pools to two different amounts of mana, and see how it goes.

The other solution is to rearrange your build and have a separate mana pool where both your mana gen builds will throw mana in, and have two mana spreaders linked to your portal mana pools from here.